# Core Constant expression in the hypothetical context as stated in the definition

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

Reference: [constexpr specifier (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

> constexpr variable
>
> A constexpr variable must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> ...
>
> it must have constant destruction, i.e. either:
>
> it is of class type or (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof, that class type has a constexpr destructor, and for a hypothetical expression e whose only effect is to destroy the object, e would be a core constant expression if the lifetime of the object and its non-mutable subobjects (but not its mutable subobjects) were considered to start within e.

The part that is not clear to me is what is implied by *if the lifetime of an object and its non-mutable subobjects (but not its mutable subobjects) start within the expression e, whose only effect is to destory the object, then e is considered a core constant expression*

I presume the implication is that, let's say for a class like

```cpp
class C {
public:
  C(char c) : c(c) {}
private:
  char c;
};
```

and assuming

```cpp
void foo() {
  char c;
  C(c);
}
```

the expression `C(c)` is considered core constant as the object created by means of it, lives and perishes before the end of `;`? (I acknowledge that the reproduced quote characterizes the expression as *hypothetical* but surely the standardization committee would have envisaged of a realistic usage scenario along the lines of the above definition for a core constant expression? On that same note, the above example is contrived and one in which the expression under consideration does not solely destroy the class object C; is there a use case that exactly mirrors the above definition of core constant expression?)

Comment: I changed the tag to `c++20`, because the whole section you are quoting is irrelevant and doesn't apply before C++20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
void nocomptime() {};

struct A {
    bool b;
    constexpr ~A() { if(b) nocomptime(); } 
};
```

Then the quote states that the following is allowed anywhere:

```
constexpr A a{false};
```

The reason is, approximately, that if you *hypothetically* (and that's what the quote is considering) wrote

```
consteval void f() { const A a{false}; }
```

you could call `f()` as in `int main() { f(); }`, necessarily as a constant expression because it is marked `consteval`. The lifetime of `a` in this function (and all of its subobjects) begins within the evaluation of the `f()` call expression and the call would be a constant expression because, although the destructor of `a` is called, it is marked `constexpr` and because `b` is `false` it never tries to call `nocomptime` (which would disqualify the whole call to `f()` from being a core constant expression as it is not marked `constexpr`).

However,

```
constexpr A b{true};
```

is ill-formed because

```
consteval void g() { const A b{true}; }
```

would not be callable (as a constant expression) as the destructor of `b` would try to call the non-`constexpr` function.

---

In your own example `C(c)` is *not* a constant expression because `c` isn't usable in constant expressions. In fact, it has no value and so even if it was usable, its use would have undefined behavior and would therefore disqualify from being a constant expression.

---

Note that I simplified in my example with the functions `f` and `g` to give a bit of a more intuitive reasoning. The actual rule is a bit different. It specifically requires *only* the destruction to be a *core constant expression* (and that separately the full-expression of the initialization be a *constant expression*), not that the initialization together with the destruction be a constant expression.

That's for example not the same if the constructor of the class allocates memory and only frees it in the destructor. In that case the initialization of the `constexpr` variable itself would not qualify as a constant expression, although initialization together with destruction would, because it is required that dynamic memory is freed in the same constant expression in which it was allocated.

Also, the storage duration will affect the behavior and the above also ignores the special casing of mutable subobjects.